# Using a std::vector<std::unique_ptr>> to another class / function

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, stdvector

I'm having some trouble refactoring a class that uses a std::vector of unique_ptrs. I currently have a class similar to:

```
class DataItemA
{
  // various data members
};

class DataItemB
{
  // various data members
};

class PointerOwner
{
public:
  PointerOwner();
  ~PointerOwner();

  void ComplexCalculationOnItemA()
  {
    for (auto itr = aItemsIOwn.begin(); itr != aItemsIOwn.end(); ++itr)
    {
      DataItemA& itemA= (**itr);

      // complex calculations that also reference DataItemB items
    }
  } 

  // methods to add / remove items from the collections
private:
  // This class owns the DataItems and control their lifetime.
  // The objects cannot live outside of this instance.
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<DataItemA>> aItemsIOwn;
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<DataItemB>> bItemsIOwn;
};
```

I was refactoring the class to extract the complex calculation to another class and was unsure how to pass the vector of unique_ptrs to the other class and clearly 'state' that the calculation does not own the pointers.  Is it reasonable to:

```
class ComplexItemAProcessor
{
  ComplexItemAProcessor(const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<DataItemA>>& itemsToProcess)
  {
    // can I store the itemsToProcess in a member variable
  }

  SomeReturnType runCalcuation() {}

private:

  // store the reference to calculation
}
```

Or is this better which can be done:

```
class ComplexItemAProcessor
{
  ComplexItemAProcessor()
  {

  }

  SomeReturnType runCalcuation(const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<DataItemA>>& itemsToProcess)
  {
    // process the collection as per original class
  }
}
```

The lifetime of the ComplexItemAProcessor would be limited to scope of the original method.

```
class PointerOwner
{
public:
  PointerOwner();
  ~PointerOwner();

  ComplexCalculationOnItemA()
  {
    ComplexItemAProcessor processor; /** ? pass here **/

    SomeReturnType result = processor.runCalcuation(/* ? pass here */);
  } 
private:
  // This class owns the DataItems and control their lifetime.
  // The objects cannot live outside of this instance.
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<DataItemA>> aItemsIOwn;
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<DataItemB>> bItemsIOwn;
};
```

Is either of these better than the other? Neither feels right to me, but that could be my limited experience with smart pointers in general. Is there another way for another class to process the vector without transferring ownership?

I don't think I need shared_ptrs as PointerOwner is the only owner.

Comment: Why don't you just pass a `const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<DataItemA>>&` to `runCalculation`?

Comment: Alternatively, look at `boost::ptr_vector`.

Comment: You cannot make a copy of that vector. It would mean copying those pointers and they are non-copyable as the "unique" name implies. Can't you leave the loop itself where it was and only pass each element to `runCalculation()`?

Comment: @DanielFrey - That's actually what I meant to put in the question as the parameters.  I've edited the question to reflect that. Is passing a const reference of vector considered a good practice?

Comment: Yes, it's usually good practice. Just make sure that you don't run into problems because of the lifetime, in your case that means it's probably better to pass it to `runCalculation` directly and not store it somewhere else. Storing a reference it something that requires care, passing a reference as a parameter is a no-brainer in 99.99% of all cases.

Comment: const reference of vector is good practice except here, where you are explicitly handing over the ownership by using unique_ptrs. You cannot have it both ways use a const vector to avoid a copy and use unique_ptr to transfer ownership.